# OpenCV4Android cvtColor crash

Tags: android, opencv, canny-operator, bitwise-or

Below is my code:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    Mat input_image = inputFrame.rgba();
    Mat output_image = new Mat(input_image.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    Mat output_image2 = new Mat(input_image.size(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
    Mat output_image3 = new Mat(input_image.size(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
    Imgproc.Canny(input_image, output_image, 100, 200);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(output_image, output_image2, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA, 4);
    bitwise_or(input_image, output_image2, output_image3);
    return output_image3;
}
```

My app always crashes after running for sometime(about 2 mins). However if I comment out cvtColor line & bitwise_or line and return output_image, then it works just fine.

I am using cvtColor to increase the number of channels, but becuase of it my app is crashing. Why is that happening? Is there any other way to increase the number of channels?

I am new to OpenCV as well as Android Development so I don`t know much. Please help. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Somehow this code is working(not sure why) but its not doing anything(no edge detection):

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    Mat rgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    Mat mIntermediateMat = new Mat();
    Imgproc.Canny(rgba, mIntermediateMat, 80, 90);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mIntermediateMat, rgba, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA, 4);
    bitwise_or(inputFrame.rgba(), rgba, rgba);
    return rgba;
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the logcat output as well?, I guess it may be due to `OOM` Out Of Memory.

Comment: @ZdaR just added the error message in logcat file. Please help!

Comment: I don't think this error message is related to `OpenCV` in any way.

Comment: Did you try perform cvtColor before Canny's edge detection?

Comment: @MrOnyszko In that case I am just getting a color image. No edge detection. And the app still crashes after sometime.

Comment: @ZdaR I ran the program again. Got the above warning message this time. Does that help?

Comment: @Ank maybe because you have altered the parameter values of `Imgproc.Canny(rgba, mIntermediateMat, 80, 90);`

Comment: @ZdaR but it is not detecting edges